# access dict element with dot

Tags: python, dictionary

I try to access element of dict with dot but not work:

```
x = {'key':'value'}
print(x.key)
```

it report error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Comment: try : `x['key']`

Comment: it can be done like:  ````print(x.keys())````

Comment: It could be done with something like [dotwiz](https://dotwiz.readthedocs.io)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dictionaries cannot be acces via a dot.
to acces dictionaries used

```
my_dict["my_key"]
my_dict.get("my_key")
```

if you want such an object I suggest using named tuples or dataclasses (named tuples are lighter).

```py
from collections import namedtuple

MyName = namedtuple('MyName', 'key1 key2')

my_obj = MyName(**{"key1": 2.5, "key2": 1.5})
```

```
my_obj.key1
>>> 2.5
```